# background-attachment fixed alternatives

Tags: javascript, html, css

I just had an issue, that I have 2 hero image sections on the same page, and I had to use `background-attachement: fixed` on them. Don't have to say, that the scroll is very slow on most browsers (looking at you IE). So the performance is not very good. Oh and this site has also some parallax scrolled elements (with stellar.js)
with smooth scroll (used: nicescroll.js for this). Ofcourse I made the images as small as possible and try not to use `background-size: cover` (performance again).
Oh and I use the `window.requestAnimationFrame()` in my core.js file (performance again).

Is there a way to make this 2 hero sections images work like `background-image: fixed` ?

**index.html**

```
<div class="first-hero">

</div>
<div class="content">
    .
    .
    lots of parallax content goes here
    .
    .
</div>
<div class="second-hero">

</div>
```

**style.css**

```
.first-hero{
  background: transparent url('image1.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height:400px;
  width:100vw;
}
.second-hero{
  background: transparent url('image2.jpg') no-repeat;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  height:350px;
  width:100vw;
}
.content{
  width:100vw;
  height:2500px;
}
```

Comment: have you tried wrapping the background image div inside another one to see if it helps???

Comment: @Toxide82 yes. tried it. didn't worked for me.

Comment: you have spelt 'attachement' wrong in your CSS should be 'attachment'... not sure if that's in your code or just on here :)

Comment: @Toxide82 I just write it here on the flow. Believe me, you dont want that huge "wall of text" here, but i will correct it right now. Thanks!

Comment: no worries i added an answer below - I'll edit that part out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Historically, `background-attachment:fixed;`has always suffered from performance issues. I would suggest that instead of this, a `position:fixed;` element is used instead.

Then, you can make the fixed background and the scrollable content sections sit on their own layers in the GPU, by using `transform:translateZ(0);` - this should offer additional performances gains.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gstnr9w5/1/

```
.fixed-background{
  position:fixed; 
  left:0;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background:url(https://unsplash.it/1000/1000?image=1080);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center center;
  z-index:0;
}

.content{ position:relative; z-index:1; color:white; font-size:22px; line-height:32px; font:serif; padding:80px; }


.fixed-background, .content{
  transform:translateZ(0);
  -webkit-transform:translateZ(0);
  -moz-transform:translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be a solution for when the element that contains the background image is needed to scroll in and out of view also, which is quite a popular need at the moment.

Comment: @biscuitstack that's true - that effect can be achieved in a performant way but it's not so straight forward. I can provide an example if needed.

Answer (score -1):

in your second hero CSS statement  try the below:

```
.second-hero{
   background: transparent url('image2.jpg') no-repeat;
   background-attachment: fixed bottom;
   height:350px;
   width:100vw;
}
```